# Does ScholarOne really force you to have multiple logins?

Tags: journals, publications, publishers

Why can't I have a single ScholarOne login for every journal I submit or review for?  Is there some way to copy over the address, keywords & password for all my accounts so I don't have to waste time making the same stuff up every time I get involved with another journal?

Comment: The real question in my opinion is "why do I need to fill in all of this stuff?". Names and affiliations of the authors are already in the paper, so there is no need to copy them back in. Author accounts can be replaced by openid. Reviewer accounts can be replaced by special links containing a unique id (many already do it). All you need is something that lets you upload a pdf.

Comment: This is an extremely irritating feature of scholar one. It means need different passwords every time you use it, or go through the hassle of changing it. There is no indication in the window which appears which of several scholar one accounts you need the password for. This rather removes the point of a password since all you need to get a new password is to type in your e-mail address, so there is no security anyway. It is particularly annoying when you are doing the journal a favour by refereeing for them.

Comment: Elsevier just combined profiles across journals.  Let's see how long it will take ScholarOne to do this ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for your question. My name is Jasper Simons and I work for Thomson Reuters, the organization behind ScholarOne. Our platform is configured by our publishers as they service their authors and editors. Publishers seek to maximize the value they offer to their journals, their editors and their authors through specific configurations of the ScholarOne peer-review workflow. This doesn't address your concern, but I hope that it sheds some light on the reasoning behind the multiple login requirements for authors. In short, there is one ScholarOne platform but there are many site configurations.

Comment: What is a "configuration" in your jargon? Does that word include the user database?

Comment: Sorry about that. Configurations refer to the specific peer-review workflow set up for a particular journal site or group of journal sites. Those are defined by the editorial office of the publisher or association. This includes choices such as "double-blind review" or not, and whether to assign manuscripts to an associate editor or directly to the editor-in-chief etc.

Comment: @Federico: ScholarOne is pursuing collaborations with ORCID to allow direct ingestion of user/author data through the ORCID. I'll separately look into why we wouldn't take such data points directly from an author submitted PDF. I suspect that there might be issues with validation of data that limit the use of such a solution but I am not sure.

Comment: Follow Up: Authors can already utilize ResearcherID or upload manuscripts through EndNote which will automatically pull your author data into ScholarOne, reducing the step to add your details manually.

Comment: This does not answer the question, in my opinion. Journal decisions about associate editors and double-blind review are orthogonal to requiring authors to set up independent profiles for each journal.

Comment: @JasperSimons Elsevier has consolidated author profiles across their journals. It has made reviewing and submitting for these journals much more pleasant.  Are you saying that it isn't possible for ScholarOne given the current technology used by your organization?

Comment: @Jasper Simons Is it possible to access my journal dashboard using two different email. For example, in edas I can access to my profile using more than email.

Comment: @JasperSimons I am wondering if you are underestimating the hassle researchers go through to use ScholarOne because of login issues. I am a reviewer and author for at least 3-4 journals using ScholarOne. Each journal requires a different login/password. When changing institution, I get a new email address and receive invitations to review to the new email address. This creates a duplicate account that I cannot merge with the older ones. My login manager has currently 15 entries for various ScholarOne logins. My submissions/reviews even for the same journal cannot be found in the same place.

Answer (score 2):

The ScholarOne platform is very capable of allowing a user to have a single login across all journals. Unfortunately, each journal (or in some cases publishers) has required their user accounts to not be shared with other journals or publishers. @aeismail answer pretty much sums up the reason (its not impossible however). At ScholarOne, we realize this is probably the most frustrating parts of the system, and are always looking for ways to help reduce the pain associated with this.

Disclaimer: I am an employee at ScholarOne, but my posts and opinions are my own!

Comment: There can be author and referee databases separated from user accounts: I log in with the same username and password, and then the server can restrict which of my user data are shared among different journals (including referee feedback scores). Does your platform allow this separation? It sounds like you are trying to shift the blame on the journals for what is really a design problem in your website.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni , The S1M system can effectively do what you describe. If you decide to submit a manuscript to IEEE, for instance, the account data is shared across  the IEEE portfolio of journals. This allows you to have the same account data with all IEEE journals, but separate author and reviewer datasets per IEEE journal. However, if you then want to submit a manuscript to an IOP journal, we are contractually (IEEE owns your original account data) and legally (think GDPR) prevented from sharing your IEEE account information with IOP. Hope this explains the situation a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

I think the primary issue is the fact that because different publishers are responsible for maintaining the different author and referee databases, it's impractical (or perhaps even impossible) to share them between different journals. If you had the ability to get somebody else's database, it would be a potentially tempting target. So I think that everything is locked to a specific journal, without the ability to transfer between them. You can probably use the same login information for all of the different journals, but you'll need to register for each one separately.

Answer (score 0):

I understand there is a reson for keeping it separate, but ScholarOne allows to connect to ORCID to get information from it (sadly only gets name and few other bits, not a real help).